# syntax error near unexpected token `else'

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to Linux and Shell scripting, so please help me with some patience.
Could you please let me know how to fix this problem?

Below is the error

```
./test.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./test.sh: line 5: `else'
```

Below is the simple if statment in shell scripting.
I use vi  editor

```
#!/bin/bash -x
age=10;
if(age -lt 13)

echo "$age"

else

echo "xx"
```

Any information is highly appreciable.

Matt

Comment: The syntax is broken.  `if [ $age -lt 13 ]; then` instead of `if(age -lt 13)`.  A closing `fi` is missing too.

Comment: You need to refer to a basic tutorial of how to write shell scripts.  I'm afraid that there's not much point in posting a completely broken snippet and asking what is wrong.

Comment: First learn basic about bash scripting and pointing to your issue first start with this http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-if-statement-examples/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't end a statement with `;`. This is not c/c++/java program.
2. Conditions in script are enclosed with `[]` not `()`
3. Please read how to use `if` statement/syntax. Do google and then try.

Syntax of `if`:

```
if [ conditional expression ]
then
    #statements
    ...
fi
```

So your program is:

```
#!/bin/bash
age=10
if [ $age -lt 13 ]
then
  echo "something"
else
  echo "some other thing"
fi
```

Comment: Well the syntax of the `if` statement is not necessarily `if [ ... ] ; then`. You can also write `if command; then` and the block will be executed if the exit status of `command` is zero